# xpages Trying to get document parentdoc is returning null error

Tags: xpages

I am trying to get the parent document of a new response document so I can duplicate the functionality of form inheritance in xpages. The following is my code and the error being returned:

```
Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=3, col=60: 'parentDoc' is null
JavaScript code

   1: if (document2.isNewNote()) {
   2: var parentDoc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByID(document2.getParentId());
   3: getComponent("immediateParentSubject1").setValue(parentDoc.getItemValueString("Subject"));
   4: }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use a dataContext and getParentDocumentUNID() when I need a handle on the parent document for the variable "document". You can use this for a new document (not saved yet):

```
<xp:this.dataContexts>
    <xp:dataContext var="parentDoc">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            try {
                if (document.isResponse()) {
                    return database.getDocumentByUNID(document.getDocument().getParentDocumentUNID());
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            } catch(e) {
                return "";
        }}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:dataContext>
</xp:this.dataContexts>
```

You can then use parentDoc in other controls and do `parentDoc.getItemValueString("Subject")` etc.

Comment: I suspect this will have the same problem when the child doc has not been saved yet.

Comment: Thank you both. Both answers were helpful. I ended up using the dataContexts as besides solving my issue worked much better for getting the parent values. Also using Panu's advice to retrieve parent docs data on open rather than storing except for elements that are needed in views. Many thanks to both.

Comment: I realized that new note was not the problem in Jim's code as I thought. It was `document2.getParentId()` which is returning UnID, not the NoteID. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`datasource.getParentId()` does not return the NoteID as you might expect. It returns the UnID and that's why you need to use `database.getDocumentByUNID` as Per is doing.

Another way is to get the parent UnID from the URL:

```
param.get("parentId")
```

Consider also looking up the parent subject whenever a child is opened instead. That way it is stored only in one place which is always a good thing.